# Calculate new field from existing fields using expression in gdal/ogr and append to shapefile

Tags: gdal, ogr, fields-attributes

I'm trying to calculate a new field from existing fields based on a simple expression for a set of polygons in GDAL/OGR.

The expression is basically:

new field = (field 1 / field 2) * field 3

After calculating, I need to append the new field on to the existing set of polygons and sum all the values in that new field.

This is very straightforward in ArcGIS or using ArcPy, but I can't find a solution for GDAL/OGR.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the one-liners for you, please check them for field/filenames etc.

Add a new field:

```
ogrinfo input.shp -sql "ALTER TABLE input ADD COLUMN field3 integer(5)"
```

Do the math (you will need your SQLite driver to be compiled with [SQLite SQL dialect](https://gdal.org/user/sql_sqlite_dialect.html)):

```
ogrinfo input.shp -dialect SQLite -sql "UPDATE input SET field3 = field1/field2"
```

I don't see where you need to Join in this case, but here an example for you:

```
ogr2ogr -sql "select input.*, table.* from input LEFT JOIN 'table.dbf'.table ON input.id = table.IDINT" output.shp input.shp
```

I didn't include summing up as it seems to be too trivial.

Comment: This solution worked nicely! I was also able to perform the summation with the following:
`ogrinfo input.shp -dialect SQLite -sql "SELECT SUM(field) from input`

Comment: Is there a way to write out the sum to a .txt file or another format?

Comment: Simply adding `> out.txt` to the end of my command allows for the result to be written to a text file

Comment: I am trying to do something similar (recalculating an already existing column in a geodatabase) so I tried the suggestions here (first just trying to run an update, then trying to remove the column altogether and add it back) and nothing seems to be changing at all in my .gdb, but no errors are reported either. Thoughts?